# Angularjs can't find the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am so new in Angularjs .I create a mvc project in VS2015.In the layout page i added these files:

```
<html data-ng-app="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        @RenderBody()


</body>
</html>
```

I added a java file called home-Index.js to js folder :

```
//home-index.js
function homeIndexController() {
    alert("hello word");
}
```

I have another view called `index` and here you can see the content

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<script src="~/js/home-Index.js"></script>
<div data-ng-controller="homeIndexController">
</div>
```

I am expecting to see the alert `hello world` but nothing happens.Why ?

Comment: did you define your angular module? something along the lines of var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

Comment: @Ozrix No i didn't because in the video that i am learning it doesn't create any module

Comment: Which angular version is this?

Comment: the version that i installed is 1.5.5

Comment: Do you use minification? If yes maybe that is your problem

Comment: You need to define your module first and then reference it in ng-app. I'd recommend following a different video if it doesn't go into this.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be related to Angular2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you passed version 1.3 you have to define your module as Ozrix stated in the comments. In addition, you also have to attach your controller to it:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]); 
myApp.controller('homeIndexController', homeIndexController);
```

Comment: I added it to the top of  my index-home.js file

Comment: After you've loaded all of your controller/directives/factory files, since you need to register them all. I create an `app.js` file and place it there.